# Sliding Up Panel Layout Listener implementation. Secondary layout visibility issues

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I'm using sliding up panel from umano https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel. I'm facing a minor and silly issue, but I'm not able to fix it. The sliding panel's secondary layout has a text view. When I expand it by dragging upwards, I want the textView to slowing fade and disappear(as in SoundCloud music app). And when I drag it back down the textView should be visible again. How to fix that? I tried a lot, but I failed.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Sliding up panel marked in red.

MainActivity.java

```
 slidingUpPanelLayout = 
(SlidingUpPanelLayout)findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);


    slidingUpPanelLayout.addPanelSlideListener(new 
SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {

            SongNameSlide.setVisibility(panel.INVISIBLE);
            ArtistNameSlide.setVisibility(panel.INVISIBLE);
            buttonabc.setVisibility(panel.INVISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, 
SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState previousState, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState newState) {
            if(newState.equals(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED)&& 
previousState.equals(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED)){
                SongNameSlide.setVisibility(panel.GONE);
                ArtistNameSlide.setVisibility(panel.GONE);
                buttonabc.setVisibility(panel.GONE);
                slidingUpPanelLayout.setDragView(panel);


            }

        else {

                SongNameSlide.setVisibility(panel.VISIBLE);
                ArtistNameSlide.setVisibility(panel.VISIBLE);
                buttonabc.setVisibility(panel.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    slidingUpPanelLayout.setFadeOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

 slidingUpPanelLayout.setPanelState (SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `PanelSlideListener` to the sliding panel and the function `onPanelSlide()` will be called with panel layout and offset values whenever the panel will be moved by the user. You can add it as:

```
slidingUpPanelLayout.addPanelSlideListener(
    new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
            SongNameSlide.setAlpha(slideOffset);
            ArtistNameSlide.setAlpha(slideOffset);
            buttonabc.setAlpha(slideOffset);
        }
    }
);
```

Now, you'll get the offset which ranges from 0 to 1 indicating how much the panel has been opened. Use this offset value and set it as `alpha` of the UI elements you want to hide.

As I don't know for which values it will be fully opened, if it works just opposite as required, use those in this way -> `SongNameSlide.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);`

Comment: ah! There it is! It was so simple. Sorry for my silly question, I,m new to this. By the way may I know what is slideOffset? Is it how far the panel goes?

Comment: @SebinPaul slideOffset here is the float value which is default in most cases of slider which goes to 1 for full opened and 0 for fully closed so by allocating this value to setAlpha value slowly changes to 0 to 1 or vice-versa and that slowly disappear/appear effect occurs.

Comment: Nice one! Thank you for your time mate!

Comment: No problem at all.